# how is Linux kernel's free_list initialized to point to free pages?

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel

I am trying to understand how `free_list` (of free_area of zones) to points different free pages in the Linux kernel.  Can anybody explain how and where in kernel code and how they get initialized?
It seems from looking through the kernel code that the only initialization of `free_list` in code is in `zone_init_free_lists()` function of kernel/mm/page_alloc.c:

```
for_each_migratetype_order(order, t) { 
INIT_LIST_HEAD(&zone->free_area[order].free_list[t]);
                          zone->free_area[order].nr_free = 0; 
}
```

from this code `free_list` are not pointing to free_pages block ??**
Any help will be greatly appreciated .**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got how pages gets added in free list here is function flow from start_kernel().

```
       start_kernel();
       mm_init()
       mem_init()
       free_all_bootmem()
       free_all_bootmem_core()
       free_all_bootmem_core()
       __free_pages()
       __free_pages_ok()
       free_one_page()
       __free_one_page()
```

Thanks.